# XSD multiple elements with single name and different types

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm quite new to XSD and I'm stuck on a problem that seemed simple to me ... before I tried.

I would like to write a XSD for the following XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<properties>

  <double name="Value1">111.111</double>
  <double name="Value2">222.222</double>

</properties>
```

I want this XSD to be very restrictive, so that Value1 and Value2 are fixed, the only "free" values are 111.111 and 222.222.

*I also would like to force both Value1 and Value2 to be present in the XML file (though not necessarily in that order)*

So I write this XSD :

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="properties">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="double">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                     <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="Value1" use = "required"/>
                     </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="double">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                     <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="Value2" use = "required"/>
                     </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Unfortunately, my XML validator gives the following error:

```
Multiple Elements With Name 'double', With Different Types, Appear In The Model Group.
```

I know this kind of issue is known, but I can't find any convenient answer, or simply I don't get them !? Moreover I cannot use XSD 1.1.

Many thanks for any help !

Comment: I think it should be possible to define a single type for the two `double` elements, restricting the `name` attribute to a single type enumeration of the two values `Value1` and `Value2`. That wouldn't, however, ensure, that the first `double` has the `name="Value1"` and the second the `Value2`, you could only define a uniqueness of the value as an ID.

Comment: Do you want to have exactly two `double` elements? Or more of them? If there are to be exactly two then set up an id/uniqueness constraint on the `name` attribute that already is restricted to be either `Value1` or `Value2`.

Comment: Yes Martin, this is exactly what I'd like to do : exactly two double elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a slight variation of the posted answer, if you extend `xs:ID` and use `min/maxOccurs="2"`:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    
    <xs:simpleType name="tVal">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
            <xs:pattern value="Value1|Value2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:element name="properties">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="double" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                                <xs:attribute name="name" type="tVal" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
</xs:schema>
```

the requirements about a unique `name` attribute having either `Value1` or `Value2` should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an `xs:simpleType` with a restriction to limit the possible values of your `@name` attribute. Then you will need only one `doulbe` element in a sequence:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:simpleType name="tVal">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="Value1|Value2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
   <xs:element name="properties">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="double">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                     <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="tVal" use="required"/>
                     </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers !
It solves my issue as I posted it initially.
But I forgot to mention that I also would like to force both Value1 and Value2 to be present in the XML file (though not necessarily in that order).
Is it possible ?